# wkhtmltopdf passing variable in html file

Tags: php, html, wkhtmltopdf

I use wkhtmltopdf with php, and it works well.
Now, i want to add some variables from the php file to the html one, but i don't find a solution.

the PHP file:

```
<?php
    require '/path/vendor/autoload.php';
    use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf;
    $pdf = new Pdf(array(
        'no-outline',
        'margin-top'    => 0,
        'margin-right'  => 0,
        'margin-bottom' => 0,
        'margin-left'   => 0,

        // Default page options
        'disable-smart-shrinking',
));
if($_GET['file'] == 'public'){
    $pdf = new Pdf('template_public.html');
}else{
    $pdf = new Pdf('template_pro.html');
}
    $pdf->send();
?>
```

The HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Generated PDF file</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
        <div>
            {title}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can i replace the {title} in the HTML file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should replace all of the {variables} in the html files with their values, given an array of parameters.

```
$params = ["title"=>"title_val", "content" => "something", "key" => "value"];
$pdf = new Pdf();
$html = file_get_contents($templateFile);    
foreach($params as $key=>$value) {
    $html = str_replace("{".$key."}", $value, $html);
}

//Renders the pdf directly from the html string, instead of loading the file directly
$pdf->addPage($html);
$pdf->send();
```

Comment: i'm not sure that will do the job

Comment: kept forgetting params and return values. otherwise, why not? ok, should be a complete example now.

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this for setting page options.

https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf#setting-options

You can set title,page number etc... 
Use **addPage** option to apply page options to specific page.

Answer (score 0):

My task is to pass real client ip value to pdf. When I read IP as $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR} I got server IP, not client IP.

I use this code to solve the problem:

```
wkhtmltopdf --cookie remote_addr $IP
```

It passes IP variable to pdf. Then, my html page can read cookie values and show them inside text.